# Colimit of Disjoint Metric Spaces vs Topological Coproduct

Tags: algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, category-theory, limits-colimits, functors

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint metric spaces.  Here we use the convention that a metric space can *assume infinite distance*.  Let **Met** be the category with metric spaces as objects and non-expansive maps as morphisms.  Let $F:Top\to Met$ be the forgetful functor, where *Top* is the category of topological spaces as objects with continuous maps as morphisms.

Then, unless I'm mistaken, the coproduct $\coprod_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^{Met} X_i$ in **Met** is the set-theoretic coproduct with metric given by
$$
d(f,g):=\begin{cases}
d_i(f,g): & f,g \in X_i\\
\infty :& else
\end{cases}
,
$$
where $d_i$ is the metric on $X_i$.  Let $\coprod_{i\in \mathbb{N}}^{Top} F(X_i)$ denote the coproduct in *Top*.  Is is the case that
$$
\coprod_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^{Top} F(X_i) \cong F\left(
\coprod_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^{Met} X_i
\right)
.
$$
Or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. You metric induces the topology of the disjoint union of topological spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, but I wanted to check I didn't make a silly overseight.